# U-Boot only boots on some SD Cards

Tags: boot, partitioning, bootloader, sd-card, gpt

I'm encountering an issue where the RK3399 custom board I'm using won't boot (using U-Boot) from certain SD Cards. I'm currently working with two 16GB cards, a Gigastone one which functions and a SanDisk one which dies somewhere after the SPL.

The output of the functioning card is as follows:

```
U-Boot TPL 2020.01 (Apr 08 2021 - 16:25:39)
Channel 0: Channel 1: 256B stride
lpddr4_set_rate: change freq to 400000000 mhz 0, 1
lpddr4_set_rate: change freq to 800000000 mhz 1, 0
Trying to boot from BOOTROM
Returning to boot ROM...

U-Boot SPL 2020.01 (Apr 08 2021 - 16:25:39 +0000)
Trying to boot from MMC1
NOTICE:  BL31: v1.3(release):
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 16:24:51, Apr  8 2021
INFO:    GICv3 with legacy support detected. ARM GICV3 driver initialized in EL3
INFO:    plat_rockchip_pmu_init(1331): pd status 3e
INFO:    BL31: Initializing runtime services
INFO:    BL31: Preparing for EL3 exit to normal world
INFO:    Entry point address = 0x200000
INFO:    SPSR = 0x3c9


U-Boot 2020.01 (Apr 08 2021 - 16:25:39 +0000)

Model: Rockchip RK3399 Firefly Board (Linux Opensource)
DRAM:  3.9 GiB
PMIC:  RK808
Cannot find regulator pwm init_voltage
MMC:   dwmmc@fe320000: 1, sdhci@fe330000: 0
Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial@ff1a0000
Out:   serial@ff1a0000
Err:   serial@ff1a0000
Model: Rockchip RK3399 Firefly Board (Linux Opensource)
rockchip_dnl_key_pressed: adc_channel_single_shot fail!
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0(part 0) is current device
** No partition table - mmc 0 **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1 is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
92777 bytes read in 12 ms (7.4 MiB/s)
Found EFI removable media binary efi/boot/bootaa64.efi
Scanning disk dwmmc@fe320000.blk...
Scanning disk sdhci@fe330000.blk...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
Found 4 disks
BootOrder not defined
```

Note: The mmc0 listed above is a blank eMMC device that's also on the board.

And the output of the non-functioning card is:

```
U-Boot TPL 2020.01 (May 07 2021 - 05:17:53)
Channel 0: Channel 1: 256B stride
lpddr4_set_rate: change freq to 400000000 mhz 0, 1
lpddr4_set_rate: change freq to 800000000 mhz 1, 0
Trying to boot from BOOTROM
Returning to boot ROM...

U-Boot SPL 2020.01 (May 07 2021 - 05:17:53 +0000)
Trying to boot from MMC1
mmc_load_image_raw_sector: mmc block read error
Trying to boot from MMC2
mmc_load_image_raw_sector: mmc block read error
Trying to boot from MMC1
NOTICE:  BL31: v1.3(release):
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 05:17:03, May  7 2021
INFO:    GICv3 with legacy support detected. ARM GICV3 driver initialized in EL3
INFO:    plat_rockchip_pmu_init(1331): pd status 3e
INFO:    BL31: Initializing runtime services
INFO:    BL31: Preparing for EL3 exit to normal world
INFO:    Entry point address = 0x200000
INFO:    SPSR = 0x3c9
```

Both cards have a 32MiB unallocated space at the beginning of the card, a 1GiB ext3 partition for UEFI and the DTB, and an ext3 partition in the remainder for the Linux filesystem. The setup is identical between the two cards and was executed as follows.

```
 2025  sudo dd if=u-boot.itb of=/dev/mmcblk0 seek=$((0x4000))
 2026  sudo dd if=idbloader.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 seek=$((0x40))
 2027  sudo mkdir -p /media/kelliott/BOOT/efi/boot
 2028  sudo mkdir -p /media/kelliott/BOOT/dtb
 2029  sudo cp Image /media/kelliott/BOOT/efi/boot/bootaa64.efi
 2030  sudo cp rk3399-foresys-vcb5.dtb /media/kelliott/BOOT/dtb/
 2031  sudo tar xvf rootfs.tar -C /media/kelliott/ROOT/
 2032  sudo sync
```

I've verified that both cards use GPT partition tables. Their Sectors/track counts are both 63 and they only have slight differences in Cylinder and Total sector counts. I even double-checked that the non-functioning card isn't a knockoff using F3. What am I missing here? I'm at a loss for other reasons why two seemingly identical cards would not boot the same.

Edit 0: I've also tried making a direct copy of the functioning card to the non-functioning card without any luck.

Comment: How thorough has this custom board been tested?  Have you reviewed the SoC errata for any SD/MMC controller issues?  Have you checked for any related U-Boot patches?  Have you booted U-Boot from a good SD card, eject that SD card, insert a problem SD card, and then try reading/writing that problem SD card using U-Boot commands?  *"Both boards have a 32MiB unallocated space at the beginning of the card,"* -- Huh???  Are you calling SD cards *"boards"*?  *"I've verified that both cards use GPT partition tables."* -- That's not standard; the convention is MBR.

Comment: Why are the build dates of the U-Boot SPL programs different? Are you comparing apples to oranges?  Make an image of the *"good"* SD card, overwrite the *"faulty"* SD card with that image, and then try to boot with *"faulty"* SD card and "good" binaries.

Comment: A direct copy was actually the first thing I tried. I've updated the question to list that out.